# Geometry Nodes : Align euler to Normal vector not working with modifers

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

From the screenshot supplied you will see that the node setup is correct for align Euler (I think) but the lattice modifiers I have used (and need to keep for non destructive editing) don't seem to be passing the normal vector over to the geometry node.

[image]

Screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/39y2jo4bgra573ht8gfqm/Screenshot-2024-01-26-at-12.16.10.png?rlkey=dfwstxmt1xed6josbp21fupln&dl=0

Blend File
https://www.dropbox.com/s/anz89tf6ryz1sza/Blender%20Normal.blend?dl=0

Comment: Please insert images directly into your question rather than posting links to them where they may not be available to folks reading the question in future. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: You can also use a Capture Attribute node from the Geometry Input to capture the normal before you convert the mesh to points (which have no normal). Then Align that to Euler and use that as the rotation for your instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just delete the mesh to points node and it works.

[image]